# Getting "maps" to a remote location with hector_mapping

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, multiplemachines, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are working on generating maps to a remote command center. Our first premise was to have ROS running on multiple machines, with the sensors running on the robot and connecting to a roscore running on the remote PC. We almost have this working, but now realize this approach breaks if there are radio dropout zones (the roscore disconnects and the map breaks during the outage).

Next is to consider having the map generated at the robot (hector_slam running on the robot rather than the PC), but the map still needs to get transmitted back to the PC (and in real time if possible).

What does it take to get the maps transmitted to a remote location?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64427/getting-%22maps%22-to-a-remote-location-with-hector_mapping/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We just use plain ROS communication. Master runs on robot, operator station connects to robot's master and we just start the necessary GUI nodes. Example screencast of that [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKI378kadp8). That of course means we stream the full uncompressed [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) message over the wire, which is pretty wasteful.

Using appropriate compression the size of those could be reduced significantly. There is some discussion of this [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/28037/transfer-only-a-roi-of-an-occupancygrid/). The compressed visualization transport for maps can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/?repo=android&r=5abc45517c0915ca8cf378cba7512dc12016888b#hg%2Fcompressed_visualization_transport

From our testing it turns out that bz2 compression is even better (and more general) than png, so we will likely use that in the future.

Some tools for doing that are available [here](https://github.com/meyerj/topic_proxy). I won't be able to give any support in the next 3 weeks though, with VRC and RoboCup coming up :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-06-06**:
Thanks Stefan. This looks like our next step to try. Hopefully we can get this part working before RoboCup.